# Javascript return true if the record is exist on the database

Tags: javascript

After clicking submit button, it will check if the record is exist on the database, if exist it will return true, the problem here is I dont know how to return true

```
//button click
if(_data.hasExistingEvent(_data.getFormData())){ ==> this will check if true or false
   ///if true
}else{

}
```

I don't have problem on my query but I just want that if the form exist on the database it will return `true` and if not it will return `false`

```
....


hasExistingEvent: (data) => {
    var {  assignedTo, startDate } = data
    var s = moment(startDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A').toDate()
    var newDate = moment(s).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm")
    return  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ....("SELECT assignedTo, startDate FROM Event WHERE assignedTo LIKE '%" + assignedTo + "%' AND startDate BETWEEN '" + moment(newDate).startOf(`day`).format() + "' AND '" + moment(newDate).endOf(`day`).format() + "'", 100, function(a){
            var valid = false;
            return valid = resolve(a.length == 0) // here
        })
    })
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are returning a variable assignation with the = operator. Returning `valid = resolve(a.length == 0)` does not make any sense since you are assigning the result of `resolve(a.length == 0)` to the variable `valid`.
If you want to check for equality, use === or ==.
The first possibility here is to do:

```
  var valid = false;
  return valid === resolve(a.length == 0)
```

Or, for a more concise code, just get rid of the valid variable and return:

```
return !resolve(a.length ==0)
```